# Propel 1.7: return numeric array from relation join

Tags: php, mysql, propel

I'm currently setting up an API using Slim and Propel 1.7.

I have a simple database schema:

```
Table:Item
----------------
id | name
----------------
1  | one

Table:Item_Ingredient
----------------
id | item_id | category | value
----------------
1  | 1       | 0        | item 1
2  | 1       | 1        | item 2
3  | 1       | 2        | item 3
4  | 1       | 1        | item 1-2
```

Now I'm trying to get all the items, and join with their ingredients

```php
$items = ItemQuery::create()
    ->joinWith("ItemIngredient")
    ->find();

echo json_encode($items->toArray())
```

This retrieves what I need, however, the "ItemIngredient" property isn't in numerical array format, the output looks like this:

```
[{
   "Id": 1,
   "Name": "one",
   "ItemIngredients": {
      "ItemIngredient_0": {
         "Id": 1,
         "ItemId": 1,
         "Category": 0,
         "Value": "item 1",
         "Item": "*RECURSION*"
      },
      "ItemIngredient_1": {
         "Id": 2,
         "ItemId": 1,
         "Category": 1,
         "Value": "item 2",
         "Item": "*RECURSION*"
      },
      "ItemIngredient_2": {
         "Id": 3,
         "ItemId": 1,
         "Category": 2,
         "Value": "item 3",
         "Item": "*RECURSION*"
      },
      "ItemIngredient_3": {
         "Id": 1,
         "ItemId": 4,
         "Category": 0,
         "Value": "item 1-2",
         "Item": "*RECURSION*"
      }
   }
}]
```

How can I get these results into a numerical array instead of this associative array?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need the results in a "numerical array"?  What are you doing with the results that requires this?

Comment: for standardized JSON response of a collection of items. I see no reason or upside to have a collection of items returned as an associative array.  It also makes it faster to iterate in other languages ( such as javascript ).

Comment: That is a really good question. It seems that the model builder uses always `true` for `$usePrefix` in `toArray()` method for foreign objects. I don't think that is correct. Can you please create a issue at https://github.com/propelorm/Propel2 for that?

Comment: Old question, but I'd like to be able to do this too